Pytorch neural net transforming 1d uniform distribution to 2d gaussian
I need to train a neural network to convert a 1d uniform distribution to a 2d gaussian distribution.
I've constructed a simple feedforward network with leaky ReLu activation and trained using MMD as the loss function
d1_to_d2 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 64),
    nn.LeakyReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64,64),
    nn.LeakyReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64,64),
    nn.LeakyReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64, 2),
)

Where it takes a 1-d point and outputs a 2d one. However the output distribution keeps changing to a

Changing the depth of the network, number of weights, minibatch size, activation functions, and regulisation dont seem to change anything and I keep getting this general shape. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Why do you need to use a neutral network? It would be pretty easy to do this conversation without one. Also, which kernel are you using for your MMD loss function?

Provide code that shows the data generation process, loss function and training process
